# How to debug "Cloud ML only supports TF 1.0 or above and models saved in SavedModel format."?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I make batch predictions using Cloud ML. Some of my models work and others don't. How I do debug the models that don't work? Everything I see is a bunch of errors: `Cloud ML only supports TF 1.0 or above and models saved in SavedModel format.` in `prediction.errors_stats-00000-of-00001`. The output of `saved_model_cli show --all --dir` is (other working models give the same output)

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['prediction']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['example_proto'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['id'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: id:0
    outputs['probability'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 1)
    name: probability:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['example_proto'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['id'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: id:0
    outputs['label'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_INT64
    shape: (-1)
    name: label:0
    outputs['probability'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (-1, 1)
    name: probability:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

UPDATED: My data is in the form of TF records, so I can't do `gcloud ml-engine local predict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was due to my models being deployed on Quad core CPU. Batch predictions didn't work. Deploying models on Single core CPU fixes the problem. It seems to be a bug, which I reported.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Did you specify `--runtime-version` when you deployed the model?  By default, it is 1.0, but presumably you need TensorFlow version `1.8` or something like that. If your model uses ops that were added after 1.0, you might get this message.

(2) You can use gcloud ml-engine local predict even with TF Records. Presumably the model that is exported has a single string tensor input with dimension [None] that feeds directly into a ParseExample operation. You just follow the standard JSON API syntax in that case by sending a batch of strings containing serialize tf.Example records (base64 encoding them and using the syntax to indicate such):

```
  {"instances": [{"b64": base64.b64encode(example1), {"b64": base64.b64encode(example2}}, ...]}
```

Another (better) option  re-export it (doesn't have to be retrained, you can always export from checkpoints or SavedModel by writing a script with a few lines to load the model and export the new one) and instead of using `build_parsing_transforming_serving_input_receiver_fn` use `build_default_transforming_serving_input_receiver_fn`. Then your JSON is simple:

```
{"instances": [{"input_name": [10,3,5,6]}]}
```

If you just have the one input, you can simplify further to:

```
{"instances": [[10,3,5,6]]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
1) Yes, it is 1.9. Other models work.
2) I will try. It seems like `gcloud ml-engine local predict` is more verbose with the errors.

Comment: I created a "fake" instances via `{"example_proto": [{"b64": base64.b64encode(example.SerializeToString())}]}` and now I get the following error when running `gcloud ml-engine local predict` `prediction_lib.PredictionError: Failed to run the provided model: Exception during running the graph: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1) for Tensor u'input:0', which has shape '(?,)' (Error code: 2)`

Comment: But the following works and no error: `{"example_proto": {"b64": base64.b64encode(example.SerializeToString())}}`

Comment: @Yuri each row in the input file to `gcloud` is it's own data instance. `gcloud` will batch up each line a form a request like so: {"instances": [line1, line2, ...]} before sending to the service. So the working syntax is actually correct (corresponds to line1 above).

Comment: Also, consider exporting your model in such a way that you can directly send the features in JSON rather than encoding as a an Example Proto

Comment: @rhaertel80 Debugging didn't help, so I tried a "Monte Carlo" search over all possible parameters and it turned out that my problem is just bizarre. When I deploy my model on Quad core CPU I get those errors no matter what I do, and the same model deployed on Single core CPU works just fine! Is this a bug? Can I report it?

Comment: sure sounds like a bug

Comment: @Lak how can I report it?

Comment: @Lak but isn't this a cloud ml bug? it works perfectly fine on my multi core cpu machine. Maybe the cloud ml team can take a look at my jobs?

Comment: If you send an inquiry to the email Lak suggested, we will take a look. Please provide your project/model/version names.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and my command was:

`gcloud ml-engine local predict   --model-dir $MODEL_DIR   --json-instances $JSON_INSTANCES --verbosity debug`

The problem is my `$MODEL_DIR` was pointing to the wrong model directory. Make sure the model is in [SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#structure_of_a_savedmodel_directory)!